# Access props value in another props' validator

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I want to access a props value in another props' validator:

```
props: {
  type: {
    type: String,
    default: "standard"
  },
  size: {
    type: String,
    default: "normal",
    validator(value) {
      // below I want to access the props `type` from above.
      return (this.type !== "caution" || this.type !== "primary") && value !== "mega"
    }
  }
}
```

But I'm getting `TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined`.
Any idea?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The `this` variable in a prop's `validator` does not reference the Vue instance. And, unfortunately, there's no real way to reference another prop's value in a prop's `validator` function.

---

One thing you could do would be to set a watcher on the Vue instance's `$props` object, setting the `immediate` option to `true` so that the watcher fires when the component is created. That watcher could trigger the validation logic where `this` is a reference to the Vue instance.

Here's a simple example:

```js
Vue.config.productionTip = false;
Vue.config.devtools = false;

Vue.component('child', {
  template: '<div></div>',
  props: {
    type: {
      type: String,
      default: "standard"
    },
    size: {
      type: String,
      default: "normal"
    }
  },
  methods: {
    validateProps() {
      if ((this.type === "caution" || this.type === "primary") && this.size === "mega") {
        console.error('Invalid props');
      }
    }
  },
  watch: {
    $props: {
      immediate: true,
      handler() {
        this.validateProps();
      }
    }
  }
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app'
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <child type="caution" size="mega"></child>
</div>
```

---

Another option would be to pass an object with a `type` and `size` property as a single prop. That way the `validator` of that prop would have a reference to both values.

```js
Vue.config.productionTip = false;
Vue.config.devtools = false;

Vue.component('child', {
  template: '<div></div>',
  props: {
    config: {
      type: Object,
      default: () => ({ type: "standard", size: "normal" }),
      validator({ type, size }) {
        return !((type === "caution" || type === "primary") && size === "mega");
      }
    }
  }
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app'
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <child :config="{ type: 'caution', size: 'mega'}"></child>
</div>
```

---

(And just a note: your validation logic is probably incorrect. As it's written, the statement in parenthesis will always evaluate to `true`. I updated that logic in my examples to be what I think you meant.)

Comment: Hey man, thanks for your suggestions, I choose option 2. It is simple and makes sense. Was intrigued to know why the accessing props wasn't available which you explained. Thanks

Comment: Ah thanks for correcting this. Why can I not set the object to `default` directly? Why do I have to return it from a function.

Comment: In javascript, objects are set by reference, so if the default value was simply an object, each instance of the component using the default would be pointing to the same object. By making it a function which returns an object, a new object will be created for each component instance which uses the default.

Comment: @thanksd are you sure? `let a = {b: 1}` then  `() => a` this will return `a` containing the pointer to `b`. actually it would be real bad if return an object would create a new object with a new set of references !?

Comment: @Estradiaz, I'm not sure what you mean. Here's a fiddle example which might be helpful in understanding how object references work: https://jsfiddle.net/75j9xuvy/

Comment: worth noting also that prop validations aren't run or included in production builds, whereas this code would be, so while this gets the job done, it will take cpu cycles and add to bundle size .

Answer (score 1):

If you only need to validate once, do it simply in the mounted() handler. This fails the jest tests for us, and logs an error in the browser.

```
props: {
  type: {
    type: String,
    default: "standard"
  },
  size: {
    type: String,
    default: "normal"
  }
},
mounted() {
  if ((this.type === "caution" || this.type === "primary") && this.size === "mega") {
    console.error('Invalid props');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible. There were few propositions in VUE project but all were rejected:

https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/3495

https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/6787

https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/9925

The trivial way for such case is to use a computed property or to validate properties on `created` hook. In this case, all properties are available.