# Vue: Conditionally allow prop types based on value of another prop

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-props

I have a component with the prop `value` and the prop `range`. `range` is of type `Boolean` and defaults to `false`. `value` should be of type `String` when `range` is `false`, and of type `Array` if `range` is `true`.

Currently, I only know how to specify that `value` can be of type `String` or `Array`, but not how to attach any kind of condition to it:

```
export default {
  props: {
    value: {
      type: [String, Array]
    },
    range: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false
    }
  }
}
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Unfortunately, there's no default way to do this, you need use computed properties or mounted to do validations manually. There's a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56904327/access-props-value-in-another-props-validator) here, you can get the more info there

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Access props value in another props' validator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56904327/access-props-value-in-another-props-validator)